# Data tag в javascript?

Tags: javascript, tag

Доброго времени суток!
Я могу найти текущий день и кинуть его в alert с информацией. 
Как сделать чтобы всё это кинуть в тег???

```js
var days = new Date().getDay(); // получаем день недели -> от (0 до 6)

var DAYSTEXT = [
  "Неделя some some",
  "Понедельник какой-то текст",
  "Вторник",
  "Среда",
  "Четверг",
  "Пятница",
  "Субота"
];

if (DAYSTEXT[days].[0]) {
  console.log('asdasdasd');
}

alert(DAYSTEXT[days]);
var nowDay = DAYSTEXT[days];
console.log(nowDay);;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

innerHTML...

в место document.body можешь выбрать любой тег

```js
var days = new Date().getDay();

var DAYSTEXT = [
  "Понедельник",
  "Вторник",
  "Среда",
  "Четверг",
  "Пятница",
  "Субота",
  "Воскресенье"
];

var nowDay = DAYSTEXT[days - 1];

document.body.innerHTML = nowDay;
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает) Но я сам вот как додумался
var element = document.querySelector("#wrapper")
  var numberDay = new Date().getDay()
  var week = [
  "Неделя",
  "Понедельник какой-то текст",
  "Вторник",
  "Среда",
  "Четверг",
  "Пятница",
  "Субота"
  ];
  element.innerHTML = week[numberDay];
  
  console.log(element);
  console.log(numberDay);

Comment: И так можно...  )))  рад был помочь...   место спасибо можно принять ответ))))

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно вывести ваше значение так:

```
let element = document.getElementById('wrapper'); //лучше искать тег по id.
let content = document.createTextNode(DAYSTEXT[days]);
element .appendChild(content);
```